# C++ base class method with different input struct argument for derived classes

Tags: c++, templates, subclassing

I'm trying to create a base class defining an interface for derived classes - say a simple audio wrapper class.

```
class AudioStreamBase
{
public:
    virtual
    ~AudioStreamBase(void);

    virtual void
    open(const void * settings) = 0;

    virtual void
    start(void) = 0;

    virtual void
    stop(bool force) = 0;

    virtual void
    close(void) = 0;

    virtual int
    recover(int err) = 0;

    virtual int
    readFrames(void * buffer) = 0;

    virtual int
    writeFrames(void * buffer) = 0;

    virtual void
    printConfig(void) = 0;
};
```

As different implementations may accept different configuration parameters in Linux/Win/embedded system, I've defined the input parameter for open() as:

const **void** * settings

One possible implementation could be:

```
struct settingsA
{
   int param1;
   int param2;
   ...
};

class AudioStreamA : public AudioStreamBase
{
public:
    ...
    void open(const void* settings) { settingsA * s = (settingsA) settings; ...};
    ...
}
```

However, this doesn't seem to be very C++ - I'm used to C a lot and I'm starting with C++ after several years again. Is there a better solution? I was thinking about templating the class or the method, but as the type is a struct, I won't be able to access the parameters. And building a complex struct construct to read it's parameters seems obscure for something simple like accessing few parameters in a struct.

Comment: There are several ways but all of them boil down to knowing the exact derived type of your stream at the time of opening it. Look at C++ `iostream` hierarchy. Do you see an `open` function in the base class? No, and there's a good reason for that.

Comment: So you suggest to leave the open out of the base class and leave it up to the user to define his own open function? Probably document it into the base class, that open function is left to the user, right? As it may seem not obvious on first sight, why the "hint" for open has not been defined.

Comment: " was thinking about templating the class or the method, but as the type is a struct, I won't be able to access the parameters." .. this doesn't make any sense. You know that `struct` is the same as `class` just with a default `public:` ?

Comment: Yes this is a definite possibility. You may want to drop `open` altogether and pass the required data to the constructor instead. This is up to you. `open` is not defined in iostreams base class precisely because you cannot open a stream without knowing what it is. Does it need a filename? a string? a network socket? a GPIO register? The base class doesn't know, so it leaves the decision to someone who does know.

Comment: @Daniel Jour
The input parameter is "dynamic" dependent on the implementation for a specific platform. If defined as template: open (T & settings) { } how does one references it's internals? You can't do T.param1 as you don't know, what is behind T.

Comment: @n. 'pronouns' m
As usual, the simplest solution wasn't the most obvious to me. :-) thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the CRTP to inject the derived class into the base. Then you could define a traits helper to define e.g. which settings have to be used for some derived class. Admittedly, a bit verbose but now your code is type-safe.

If you need the base class to be non-template, you could pull out everything except the `open` into a non-template top base class.

```
class AudioStreamA;
struct settingsA;

template<class T>
struct AudioStreamTraits;

template<>
struct AudioStreamTraits<AudioStreamA> {

    using Settings = settingsA;
};

template<class Derived>
class AudioStreamBase
{
protected:
    using StreamTraits = AudioStreamTraits<Derived>;
    using Settings = typename StreamTraits::Settings;
public:
    virtual
    ~AudioStreamBase() = default;

    virtual void
    open(const Settings& settings) = 0;

    //...  

};

struct settingsA
{
   int param1;
   int param2;
};

class AudioStreamA : public AudioStreamBase<AudioStreamA>
{
    using Base = AudioStreamBase<AudioStreamA>;
    using Base::Settings;
public:
    
    void open(const Settings& settings) override {  };
};

int main() {
    AudioStreamA s;
    settingsA settings;
    s.open(settings);
    return 0;
}
```

See code example [here](https://godbolt.org/z/vsWjTs)

However, if you only need the settings in the derived class, you could simply replace the `open` by a constructor in the derived class:

```
class AudioStreamBase
{
  
public:

    virtual
    ~AudioStreamBase() = default;

    // ....
};

struct settingsA
{
   int param1;
   int param2;
};

class AudioStreamA : public AudioStreamBase
{

public:
    
    AudioStreamA(const settingsA& settings)  { } ;
};
```

Comment: Why waste time, write lot code when short code do trick? Just leave `open` out of the base class interface. Problem solved. "Oh but maybe I will want to call `open` without knowing the exact type..." [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).

Comment: Because that's what the OP was asking. But you're right, in the specific example, leaving out `open` is the better solution, which is why I added the second example. No need to be rude.

Comment: I agree, that you most probably don't need it and leaving open is the best solution, however, it's a nice example as how to potentially. Thx for the snippet florestan. :-)